# SQL join to get the records separately from two tables based on common filter between two tables

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables **Table 1 : MemberTable** and **Table 2 : PaymentTable** as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to generate a report that gets the aggregated values from both the tables as **Table 3**

I tried with full outer join and cross join but it is not working.
Can somebody help me with the query that generates the report as in Table 3.
My try :

```
Select 
month_type,
month,
engaged,
sum(amount) as amount_sum,
count(distinct member_id) as 1st_Table_Member_count,
count(distinct member_id) as 2nd_Table_Member_count 
from member_table a
full outer join 
payment_table b
on a.month=b.month
group by 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Month type is just in the B table. And you want to count member_id-s there, but you can't say this member is for which month_type. Or you want to say service and paid month the same count? If a member and month is in B table then it must be in the A table too? Have you somewhere a table where just the months/month_types are? Is the engaged flag consistent between A and B tables?(pro member_NO, and months?)

Comment: If you see the desired_output table i have mentioned above, 1st_table_member_count should only be dependent on Engaged flag.
Whereas, 2nd_table_member_count along with amount sum should be dependent on month_type of second table and also Engaged flag. and yes Engaged flag are consistent between two tables if there is a member_no match. But as shown above, some members present in 1st table may not be present in 2nd table and other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the trick,

I moved the counts to two CTE's so they are independant of each other, the sum of amounts is on the second table, as that is the only place it makes sense, at which point outer joining the two results together, should yeild all the answers.

```
WITH table_1 AS (
    SELECT
        a.month,
        b.month_type,
        a.engaged,
        count(distinct a.member_id) as table_1_count
    FROM member_table AS a
    LEFT JOIN payment_table AS b
        ON a.month = b.month AND a.member_id = b.member_id
    GROUP BY 1,2,3  
), table_2 AS (
    SELECT
        month,
        month_type,
        engaged,
        sum(amount) as amount_sum,
        count(distinct member_id) as table_2_count
    FROM payment_table
    GROUP BY 1,2,3  
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.month, b.month) AS month
    COALESCE(a.month_type, b.month_type) AS month_type
    COALESCE(a.engaged, b.engaged) AS engaged
    b.amount_sum,
    a.table_1_count as 1st_Table_Member_count,
    b.table_1_count as 2nd_Table_Member_count,
FROM member_table AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN payment_table AS b
    ON a.month = b.month AND a.member_id = b.member_id
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how the tables are structured -- particularly what the month column has to do with all this.  However you may just need to fix the `JOIN` condition:

```
Select month_type, month, p.engaged,
       sum(p.amount) as amount_sum,
       count(distinct m.member_id) as 1st_Table_Member_count,
       count(distinct p.member_id) as 2nd_Table_Member_count 
from member_table m full outer join 
     payment_table p
     using (month, member_id) 
group by 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: I am just considering one example month from my actual table. I need to generate a report month wise. Paid_Date and Service_Date, one of this is set as default filter in my expected report. But this filter should only work for Paid amount and  2nd_Table_Member_count , and 1st_Table_Member_count should not change on PD/SD filter. But when i select the Engaged filter, both types of records (i.e. 1st_Table_Member_count  and payment information including 2nd_Table_Member_count) should be grouped accordingly. Please check my 3rd table(desired output)

Comment: What is the expected result, if (month,member_id) is just in MemberTable . Then you can't   decide PD or SD. Then this (month,member_id) is null, PD, SD, OR PD and SD?